# CSS: some space event after padding-top:0% even

Tags: html, css

I want to delete any top space between the border of the div and the text but even using `padding-top:0%;` there is still some space.

I using this html code:

```css
#article-container {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
}

#article-summary {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  padding-top: 0%;
  float: left;
}

#article-summary a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div id="article-summary">
    <p>Security vulnerabilities that put customers at risk have affected Asda's website for a couple of years, a security expert has revealed.</p>
    <p><span class="date">19 January 2016 | </span><a href="">Technology</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

That results in:
[image]

Comment: p tags automatically have padding. you can just add a p{ margin-top:0; padding-top:0} to your css and it should take care of that

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue, but you're declaring styles on an `article-container` id, but it's a class in your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set margin for p tag in side article. Add :first-child if you want only first p tag

```
#article-summary p:first-child{
  margin-top:0;
  /*margin-bottom:0;*/
}
```

```css
#article-container {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
}

#article-summary {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  padding-top: 0%;
  float: left;
}

#article-summary p:first-child{
  margin-top:0;
  /*margin-bottom:0;*/
}

#article-summary a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div id="article-summary">
    <p>Security vulnerabilities that put customers at risk have affected Asda's website for a couple of years, a security expert has revealed.</p>
    <p><span class="date">19 January 2016 | </span><a href="">Technology</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
```